# Is npm react-handsontable wrapper for hands on table 4.0 or lower version of hands on table

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-handsontable) a wrapper for hands on table current version or lower version?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper available as [`react-handsontable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-handsontable) was for older Handsontable versions.

Today Handsontable Team has released updated wrapper with support for Handsontable 4.0. Also the wrapper is now available as a npm `@handsontable` scoped package. So you need to update your `package.json`:

For Handsontable CE use [`@handsontable/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handsontable/react) 
For Handsontable PRO use  [`@handsontable-pro/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handsontable-pro/react)